# Create a new table using existing tables and remove duplicates

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have two tables with a column that has phone numbers and several other columns.  There are duplicate phone numbers within each table and duplicates across the two tables.  I'd like to create a new table with only the phone numbers and no duplicate phone numbers in the new table.

Comment: `SELECT phone FROM table1 UNION SELECT phone FROM table2;` will give you distinct phone numbers from both tables in one column. Toss an INSERT statement or CREATE TABLE in front of it and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions here as you haven't really asked the question with much thought but;

```
create table dbo.Table3
     (
     PhoneNumber varchar(100)
     )
go
insert into dbo.Table3
select
    distinct PhoneNumber
from
    (
    select
        PhoneNumber
    from
        Table1
    union
    select
        PhoneNumber
from
    Table2
)nos
go
```

Comment: Matt T : Mark as the answer